# Recurrence relation in Josephus p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m

Tags: math, recurrence, josephus

The [josephus problem](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/17229) can be [solved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) by the below recursion:

```
 josephus(n, k) = (josephus(n - 1, k) + k-1) % n + 1
 josephus(1, k) = 1
```

How this recurrence relation has been derived?

Comment: Isn't that explained well enough on the wikipedia page?

Comment: If Wikipedia isn't clear enough, break out a copy of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics

Answer (score 1):

josephus(n, k) = (josephus(n - 1, k) + k-1) % n + 1    ...... (1)

To put it in simple words - 
starting with the "+1" in the formula. It implies that 1 iteration of the recurrence has already been done. Now, we would be left with n-1 persons/elements. We need to process n-1 elements recursively at intervals of k. But, now, since the last element to be removed was at kth location, we would continue from thereof. Thus, k-1 added. Further, this addition might upset the indexing of the array. Thus %n done to keep the array index within the bounds. 
Hope it is lucid and elaborate enough :) .

Answer (score 0):

This paragraph is sufficient from wikipedia..

> When the index starts from one, then the person at s shifts from the
>   first person  is in position ((s-1)\bmod n)+1, where n is the total
>   number of persons. Let f(n,k)     denote the position of the survivor.
>   After the k-th person is killed, we're left with a    circle of n-1, and
>   we start the next count with the person whose number in the original
>     problem was (k\bmod n)+1. The position of the survivor in the
>   remaining circle would be     f(n-1,k) if we start counting at 1;
>   shifting this to account for the fact that we're  starting at (k\bmod
>   n)+1 yields the recurrence
>
> `f(n,k)=((f(n-1,k)+k-1) \bmod n)+1,\text{ with }f(1,k)=1\,,`

Comment: Honestly, I could not understand this sentence: `then the person at s shifts from the first person is in position`, there are two predicates. What does "shifts" mean? Can you explain more to me? I check the Chinese and Japanese version, but this sentence is not there.